# spring security: @EnableResourceServer vs oauth2ResourceServer()

Tags: spring-security-oauth2

What is the difference between using `@EnableResourceServer` and using `HttpSecurity.oauth2ResourceServer()`? Why should I use one or the other?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`@EnableResourceServer` is an annotation from the Spring Security OAuth project that is being replaced by new OAuth features in [Spring Security 5](https://spring.io/blog/2018/01/30/next-generation-oauth-2-0-support-with-spring-security). In essence, it loads `ResourceServerConfiguration`, which extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and configures it, creating a filter chain that gives your application resource server functionality. Check out the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/config/annotation/web/configuration/EnableResourceServer.html) or its [source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/config/annotation/web/configuration/ResourceServerConfiguration.java) for more info.

`http.oauth2ResourceServer()` is in the current [Spring Security 5 reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2resourceserver) and is the way to go. It creates a `BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter` that intercepts requests, extracts any Bearer Tokens and attempts to authenticate. For more details, check out the source code for the [filter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/5.1.x/oauth2/oauth2-resource-server/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/resource/web/BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.java) or for the [configurer](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/oauth2/server/resource/OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer.java) that creates the filter.